How to configure uncrustify to only split lines at commas?
I'm using uncrustify to format my code. I have a usecase in which i wan't to prevent uncrustify from splitting lines at the dot operator.
To take an example, for the property reference MyClass.property instead of having MyClass and property at different lines, can uncrustify be configured to always maintain these as it is (MyClass.property) but still split at commas / any operators around it if the line length exceeds a given limit?
I tried eperimenting with the nl_ properties, but nothing seemed to address this particular situation
